# Replace Syscall in Userspace in various Operating Systems

Tags: c++, c, kernel, posix, system-calls

**TL;DR**: *I am trying to reroute system calls in various operating systems, so that a system call like `open` does different things than it did before*

Background Info (for those readers who do not know what System Calls are and what I want to do here):

> The operating system is divided in a Userspace (which is where your programs run) and a "kernel space" (which (can) produces nice Blue Screens/Kernel Panics if messed with). Sometimes the programs inside the userspace call the kernel for help (and they do this a lot, for example when opening a file, `open` is called). What I want to do is to replace those calls with my own calls.

So what I am trying to do is to 1. create a subprocess (easy ;-)) 2. said subprocess should automagically stop, as soon as he executes a system call (like `open()`), and some pre-defined method shall be executed instead of the original system call, allowing me to execute my stuff insted.

So this is what I found out (so far):

## Status on macOS:

I am working on macOS, here I found the wonderful `task_set_emulation` function inside the Mach Kernel, which seemed to allow me replacing parts of the system call table in user space. IF ONLY APPLE WOULD HAVE ACTUALLY IMPLEMENTED IT INSTEAD OF LEAVING THE HEADERS DANGLING AROUND :rant:

`ptrace` is also pretty crappy on macOS, so currently, I am not aware of any feasable solution

## Status on Windows:

Well, thanks MS, there is this: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/project/detours/?from=http%3A%2F%2Fresearch.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Fprojects%2Fdetours%2F

"Rerouting Win32 system calls" - thats what I want, unless any of you do know a better solution.

## Status on Linux:

Here, `ptrace` seems to work as it should (:glance: at apple), but perhaps there is a nicer way to do it, do you know any?

So, do any of you know better methods for Linux and Windows? Or any pointers on how to do this on macOS?

PS: There is one method which should work on all operating systems (pretty much the same): Loading the binary code of the program myself and rewrite the syscalls before executing the modified program. However, for obvious reasons (would break code signing, seems hacky), I would prefer not doing that.

Comment: Are you writing malware (e.g. crypto-ransomware) or trying to find out which operating systems are so bad at defending themselves from malware that they should not be used?

Comment: Neither, I am building a sandbox for native code ;-)

Comment: chroot is not an  option, because it requires root, and the LD_PRELOAD trick, or its cousin on mac, the DYDL-Preload-Trick, are both way to insecure (the program could still do a system call manually)

Comment: Did you have a look at gVisor?

Comment: @mevets Thats not really what I want to do, I want to intercept specific system calls, not run a full blown Linux kernel on mac. But thanks for the pointer, I appreciate it.

Comment: Even if you're not writing a rootkit or a debugger, maybe it's worth looking into the source code of such tools to learn how they do it. On Linux, a debugger uses `ptrace()`, and a rootkit that replaces system calls is a kernel module that does "unspeakable" things.